# How to clear DNS cache on DD-WRT

Tags: dns, dd-wrt, dnsmasq

How can I clear the DNS cache in DD-WRT on my router?

DD-WRT uses the dnsmasq daemon.

Comment: Besides the technically correct answers below, you could power cycle it...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

According to [Flush dnsmasq dns cache](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel-debian-ubuntu-flush-clear-dns-cache/):

dnsmasq is a lightweight DNS, TFTP and DHCP server. It is intended to provide coupled DNS and DHCP service to a LAN. Dnsmasq accepts DNS queries and either answers them from a small, local, cache or forwards them to a real, recursive, DNS server. This software is also installed many cheap routers to cache dns queries. **Just restart to flush out dns cache:**

```
# stopservice dnsmasq
# startservice dnsmasq
```

Comment: There is no "sudo" on dd-wrt.  There is not /etc/init.d on dd-wrt, nor any equivalent.

Comment: Hmm... The code was just a quick example. Maybe I should delete it. Alternatively do you know the correct command for this env?

Comment: The other answer has the only way that I know of for restarting services on dd-wrt. Not too clean, but I don't know any other way.

Comment: How about `stopservice dnsmasq` followed by `startservice dnsmasq`? See http://www.barrymorrison.com/tag/dd-wrt/

Comment: Hadn't heard about it.  Didn't find it after a quick google either.  Great job :)

Comment: You can do this in one command: `restart_dns`

Comment: `dnsmasq` has a `--clear-on-reload` option, which suggests to me that this answer isn't robust. Using **SIGHUP** is best.

Answer (score 20):

```
killall -1 dnsmasq
```

Send HUP signal to tell it flush the cache an reread its configuration, thus starting over with a clean slate.

Comment: I think using SIGHUP is the cleanest method because the manpage notes it, and `dnsmasq` may not clear the cache on restart. Though I'd have put `# killall -HUP dnsmasq` rather than `# killall -1 dnsmasq` because it is easier to remember/understand.

Comment: Actually it does _not_ cause it to reread its configuration – that part is incorrect – but that doesn't matter for the question because the configuration doesn't need to be reread to clear the cache.

Answer (score 6):

Since there are no init scripts on DD-WRT, I guess this would be the easiest way to restart dnsmasq:

1. Kill dnsmasq:

   ```
   root@ddwrt6:~# killall dnsmasq
   ```
2. Start dnsmasq:

   ```
   root@ddwrt6:~# dnsmasq --conf-file=/tmp/dnsmasq.conf
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I've always used:

```
killall -1 dnsmasq
```

which has worked fine for me.  I'm running some of the newer versions of DD-WRT and

```
stopservice dnsmasq
startservice dnsmasq
```

also seemed to work without error or needing sudo...

Answer (score 2):

Restart the dnsmasq service, either from the user interface.

Or from the command line interface via

```
/init.d/dnsmasq restart
```

Answer (score 2):

On 21.02 this is what worked.

```
service dnsmasq restart
```